# Angular ui-router: Is there a way to set a template load timeout?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to set a default "time out" for a template load?

My template says "pending" (Chrome > Network Tab) even after a minute. It's an intermittent problem...just every once in a while a template will take an indefinite amount of time to load.

What I would like is to be able to handle the error instead of waiting indefinitely for my page to load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an obvious way to do this. When you supply `templateUrl`, the `$http` request that is made does no have a `timeout` property. To be able to cancel, you'd need to make your own `$http` call.

This is possible with a `templateProvider` property. You can wrap this functionality in a service to make it less cluttered:

```
.factory("viewTemplateSvc", function($http, $templateCache){
  return {
    get: function(url, timeout){
      return $http
        .get(url, { 
              cache: $templateCache, 
              headers: { Accept: 'text/html' },
              timeout: timeout // timeout in milliseconds
            })
        .then(function(response) { 
          return response.data; 
        });                  {
    }
  }
})
.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
     .state("stateA",
              {
                templateProvider: function(viewTemplateSvc){
                  return viewTemplateSvc.get("views/stateA.html", 2000);
                },
                // etc...
              });

})
```

This is, of course, rather messy and not very DRY. You can, of course, rely on some default timeout, but you need to specify the `templateProvider` for every state.

One way to avoid this, is to use `$stateProvider.decorator` and substitute every occurance of `templateUrl` with `templateProvider`:

```
$stateProvider.decorator("views", function(state, viewsFn){
  var views = viewsFn(state);
  angular.forEach(views, function(config, name){
    if (config.templateUrl){
      var url = config.templateUrl;
      config.templateUrl = undefined;

      config.templateProvider = function(viewTemplateSvc){
         return viewTemplateSvc.get(url, 2000);
      }
    }
  });
  return views;
});
```

Then, you could just continue using `templateUrl` as before.

Comment: This is great but where do I handle the error? In the "then"?

Comment: @redconservatory, it would probably be best to handle where you'd handle any state change error (like when one of the `resolve` values is rejected) - in the `$stateChangeError` handler